# Arista 7050S-52

Tags: arista

I have a Arista 7050S-52 and i have read its datasheet but i could not find much information,
i have around 600 interface vlan, 3k ipv4 routes, 6x bgp neighbor with no full table, some simple access list for control switch , i will use copp, my traffic is about 12gbps and 5mpps , and each interface vlan may have 2-3x /28 or /29
do you think it can handle my traffic with no extra overload ?
THank you.

Comment: That's even older than the 5K or the 3K you asked about before.

Comment: i know, but i have them in stock, and has more feature than those 5k and 3k, does arista 7050 able to handle that much of traffic that i told you?